# Java Script Function Not working

Tags: javascript

Please refer to following section of a Form code.  When I click 'SAVE 1' button, nothing happens. On clicking 'SAVE 2' button, alert is displayed. Not sure why 'display(') is not getting invoked on clicking 'SAVE 1' button.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
function display()
{
alert("Hello there");
}
</script>

<button id="myFormSubmit1" type="button" class="btn btn-default" onClick='display();'>SAVE 1</button>
<button id="myFormSubmit1" type="button" class="btn btn-default" onClick='alert("Hello there")'>SAVE 2</button>
```

Comment: The first button is missing the opening `<`, is that a typo in the question?

Comment: Works just fine -> http://jsfiddle.net/jCLbe/

Answer (score 0):

Do your button elements have actually the same id?
You need to make the id unique I guess.

```
<button id="myFormSubmit1" type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick='display();'>SAVE 1</button>
<button id="myFormSubmit2" type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick='alert("Hello there")'>SAVE 2</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the button id,it looks same it may not work

Answer (score 0):

yes change your button id . if u want to use same id means use jquery like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$(".btn").click(function()
{
 alert("you get particular button attribute")
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Where did you put your js code? I am sure if you put it in the right place, it should work.

1. button ids should not be same.
2. move your script to the bottom of the body and I believe it should work.

Answer (score 0):

as everyone else suggested, the button id's have to be different but  **only if you try to access the buttons**,

your issue lies somewhere else. the button id's have **nothing to do with your issue**

the problem is that you have put your script in the wrong place.
put it in the `<head>` section and it will work.

here is an example: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/CBH4d/)

*note on the top left panel i chose to appent the scripts `in <head>` section.

Comment: Issue got resolved after moving function definition to <HEAD> Section.

Comment: If my answer helped resolving the issue, please consider accepting it by clicking the green V on its left side  :)